# Learning functional/Clojure programming - practical exercises?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

I'm learning functional programming with Clojure. What practical exercises can you recommend? Online repositories with solutions would be perfect.

One idea I can think of is going through all the popular algorithms on sorting, trees, graphs etc. and implementing them in Clojure myself. While it could work, it may be pretty steep and I'm likely to do it inefficiently (compared to someone who knows what she's doing).

Comment: https://clojurecademy.com is very nice resource

Comment: "https://github.com/DerekCuevas/interview-cake-clj/tree/master/apple-stocks/src/apple_stocks" "https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition-Clojure"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would recommend doing the Project Euler exercises:

http://projecteuler.net/

> Project Euler is a series of
>   challenging mathematical/computer
>   programming problems that will require
>   more than just mathematical insights
>   to solve. Although mathematics will
>   help you arrive at elegant and
>   efficient methods, the use of a
>   computer and programming skills will
>   be required to solve most problems.

Because many programmers are solving Project Euler exercises, you can compare the solutions to other (non-functional) programming languages, but also Clojure solutions are available: http://clojure-euler.wikispaces.com/, so you can contrast imperative vs. functional/idiomatic Clojure.

Of course you will learn the most by first doing the exercises yourself, without consulting any of the solutions.

Comment: The site http://clojure-euler.wikispaces.com/ is no longer available as the wiki has expired

Answer (score 22):

At the time this question was asked, [4clojure](https://github.com/4clojure/4clojure) had been launched recently. It took a lot of inspiration from Functional Koans, and several of the puzzles from 99 Lisp Problems; but it aimed to improve on both by providing a learning experience for which you need only your browser.

Since then, the original 4clojure has been [decommissioned](https://groups.google.com/g/clojure/c/ZWmDEzvn-Js/m/ad4gKdLEAgAJ), but its problems were migrated to [4ever-clojure](https://4clojure.oxal.org/).

Problems vary in difficulty from language tutorials like [What is the second element of this list?](https://4clojure.oxal.org/#/problem/12) to thought-provoking questions like [Is it possible to arrange these N words so that each differs from the preceding one by at most one character](https://4clojure.oxal.org/#/problem/82).

Comment: @Javi12 Thanks for bringing this answer to my attention. I've updated it to point to the successor site.

Answer (score 13):

Try [99 Lisp Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html). The solutions aren't in clojure, but it should be easy to translate.

Answer (score 10):

I recently started learning Clojure myself, and found [*labrepl*](http://github.com/relevance/labrepl) useful.

It lets you get familiar with the basics and the REPL, contains a number of exercises and describes quite a bit of non-obvious stuff that is hard to find in the documentation since you don't yet know what you are looking for.

Recommended.

**Edit**

Also the [Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/), a series of puzzles that can be solved by a few lines of programming; the solution to a puzzle gives you the URL to visit for the next puzzle.

Although not specifically Clojure, the puzzles are quite entertaining and a good way to get your feet wet with any new language IMHO. (There are a couple of puzzles that are specific to Python, but the majority are not. See the [forum for Python Challenge Hints](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=1) when stuck.)

The Python Challenge differs from the Euler tasks in being more practical and less math oriented; tasks include things like filtering the bytes of an image and following hyperlinks programmatically.

Answer (score 8):

There are some Functional Koans for Clojure: https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans

I have not gotten round to trying these, but have heard good reviews.

Comment: This article describes how to get started with koans for three languages including clojure: http://sett.ociweb.com/sett/settJan2011.html#clojure-koans

Answer (score 7):

As a once-upon-a-time LISP programmer, I found Clojure Koans https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans extremely efficient and methodically sound.

Use a three window arrangement (editor + evaluator + repl) for instant feedback, documentation reference and on the fly experimenting.

The topics of the "tutorial" are well organized and gradually introduce more complex material. Certainly a good starting point if you have at least some LISP experience.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommended studying the code in [clojure.contrib](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/) on github.

As an exercise for learning FP I would recommend just writing the apps you're currently working on in Clojure, but try not to use any Refs or loops. Be dedicated to solving your problems functionally using recursion. If you think you have to use a Ref or a loop make sure you can explain why that is.

Answer (score 2):

http://exercism.io/ has several not-so-trivial exercises, they give you a test and a description, you submit a solution and you refactor by looking at other people's code I highly recommend it, plus it's polyglot you can do the exercises in any programming language they support.

As others have mentioned Project Euler is a great place to start. But pick a good book that will teach you the fundamentals and the rationale for clojure's implementation, Programming Clojure by Stuart Halloway comes to mind.

Once you're done with that Timothy Baldridge offers several video tutorials where he dissects core.async, transducers, logic programming and lots of other fun stuff to play around with at: https://tbaldridge.pivotshare.com/

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend Hackerrank, it has functional programming domain: https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/fp/intro

You may check your skills not only with clojure, but haskell, scala, erlang and many more